# How to show D3 chart using Bootstrap modal popup when click on button and download it as image format

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I want to show d3 chart using bootstrap modal popup and download it as image format.

I have tried using bootstrap modal but do not know how to use javascript function which is having D3 chart inside  bootstrap modal-body and how to download d3 chart as image format

**Sample code**

```
var path0  = [{x: 1.0, y: 8.5},{x: 2.0, y: 5.0}, {x: 1, y: 1.5}];
  var path1 = [{x: 3, y: 8.5},{x: 4.0, y: 5.0}, {x: 3, y: 1.5}];
  var path2 = [{x: 5, y: 8.5},{x: 6.0, y: 5.0}, {x: 5, y: 1.5}];
  var path3 = [{x: 7, y: 8.5},{x: 8.0, y: 5.0}, {x: 7, y: 1.5}]; 
  var path4  = [{x: 1.78, y: 5.0},{x: 1.8, y: 5.0}];
  console.log(path0);

  var w = 1200,
      h = 850,
      p = 40,

      x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([p, w - p]),
      y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([h - p, p]);



  var line = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate("cardinal")
            .x(function(d) { console.log(d);return x(d.x); })
            .y(function(d) { console.log(d); return y(d.y); });



  var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
            .append("svg:g"); 

  var rules = vis.selectAll("g.rule")
              .data(x.ticks(10))
              .enter().append("svg:g")
              .attr("class", "rule"); 

  rules.append("svg:line")
        .attr("x1", x)
        .attr("x2", x)
        .attr("y1", p)
        .attr("y2", h - p - 1);

  rules.append("svg:line")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return d ? null : "axis"; })
        .attr("y1", y)
        .attr("y2", y)
        .attr("x1", p)
        .attr("x2", w - p + 1);

  rules.append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", x)
        .attr("y", h - p + 3)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(x.tickFormat(10));

  rules.append("svg:text")
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("x", p - 3)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(y.tickFormat(10)); 

 vis.selectAll("path.path0")
      .data([0])
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", function(d) {  console.log(d);return line.tension(d)(path0); }) 
      .style("stroke","green");
      vis.append("text")
    .attr("x", (w / 2))             
    .attr("y", (h / 2))
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
    .style("font-size", "16px") 
    .text("test2");        

  vis.append("text")
        .attr("y", 425)
        .attr("x",241.6)
        .attr("dy", 10)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("test1"); 


        vis.append("text")
        .attr("y",4)
        .attr("x",5)
        .attr("dx", 15)
        .attr("dy",15)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("test"); 




  vis.selectAll("path.path1")
      .data([0])
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", function(d) {  console.log(d);return line.tension(d)(path1); })
      .style("stroke","green");
```

Here is my sample d3 chart [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2yn3b4p/)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I figured it out. You just need to change line 24 of your JavaScript file to say:

```
var vis = d3.select("#yourDivID").append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
            .append("svg:g");
```

Instead of targeting the "body." That way it writes to the div with the specified ID, and you can place:

```
<div id="yourDivID"></div>
```

Into your HTML file wherever you need to place the SVG image (i.e. within your modal body tag).

Here's my update to your fiddle where I've got it writing to the div: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2yn3b4p/2/)

You may need to update width and height to fit appropriately within your modal, otherwise you could target the svg via CSS make it behave responsively the same way you would a regular image.

Comment: Thanks and Sorry for late reply. How to save this d3 chart as image format ?

Comment: It is already outputting the chart as an SVG image (Scalable Vector Graphic): [What is SVG](http://webdesign.about.com/od/svg/a/what-is-svg.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already creating an svg image, so you just need to place it.

I created a chart in a separate HMTL page, like you've already done, then targeted a specific ID in my JavaScript file for it to append to when I want to display it in another HTML page. To do this, add this at the end of your code:

```
var baseSvg = d3.select("#yourDivID").append("svg");
```

Then in the page you want to display it in, add a link to d3.js as well as the JavaScript file you're using to create the chart, then within your modal-body div add:

```
<div id="yourDivID"></div>
```

Since your chart is a specific size, you can style this div or it's parents accordingly.

Comment: I have two files one is js which contains d3 chart and other one is html which includes d3 chart js file, added var baseSvg = d3.select("#yourDivID").append("svg"); to javascritp file. In html file I have added <div id="yourDivID"></div> under bootstrap Modal body as you mentioned. But popup is showing blank, not having d3 chart on it

Comment: Where am I supposed to use baseSvg Javascrit variable and how?

Comment: It sounds like you've put everything in the right place. Are you looking at it on your local host or publishing it to a website? I have to publish mine for the chart to generate. It doesn't work locally.

Comment: I am using at my local machine,But we can run this also on local.I do not know how to use **var baseSvg**  as you defined in your code.